# How to edit this code to wait for a file fully uploaded with node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Hi I am trying to download a file and when it downloads it first has the extension .tmp or .crdownload, then after it is fully downloaded the extension changes to whatever the correct extension is, for example .png. I want to wait until the file no longer has the extension .tmp or .crdownload and then save the new file path to a variable. How can I do this? I have looked here on Stack Overflow but it is not answering all my questions. This is a unique and specific question. That is what I have so far. I don't mind if you don't use this code as long as the resulting code waits for the extension to change and saves the path to a variable as a string.

Code:

```
    var downloadanduploadpath = "C:/Users/user1/Downloads";

    //ptc mean path to check. have differnt name so the variable name of the placeholder in the function call is not the same name as the variable name in the function
                var ptc = downloadanduploadpath;
                
                var pathtocheck = ptc;
    
                var timetowaitforimagefiledownloaded = 5000;
                
                var fs = require('fs');
    
                //let dirToCheck = pathtocheck;
    
                var filecheckerfiles = fs.readdirSync(pathtocheck);
    
                var filecheckerlatestPath = `${pathtocheck}/${filecheckerfiles[0]}`;
                var filecheckerlatestTimeStamp = fs.statSync(filecheckerlatestPath).mtime.getTime();
                
    
                
                
                filecheckerfiles.forEach(filecheckerfile => {
    
                  var filecheckerpath = `${pathtocheck}/${filecheckerfile}`;
    
                  var filecheckertimeStamp = fs.statSync(filecheckerpath).mtime.getTime();
    
                  if (filecheckertimeStamp > filecheckerlatestTimeStamp) {
                    filecheckerlatestTimeStamp = filecheckertimeStamp;
                    
                    lastdownloadedimagetimestamp = filecheckerlatestTimeStamp;
                    lastdownloadedimage = filecheckerpath;
                  }
                });
    
                
                //get the extention of the last downloaded image
                var lastdownloadedimageextention = lastdownloadedimage.split(".").pop();
                
                //"png" || "jpg" || "jpeg" || "gif" || 
    
                //if the file is a .tmp the image is not fully downloaded. run code inside to wait for it to not be a tmp file showing that the image if fully downloaded
                if((lastdownloadedimageextention == "tmp") || (lastdownloadedimageextention == "crdownload") ){
                    
                    //Show the file path to the console
                    console.log(lastdownloadedimage);
                    
                    //show file not fill downloaded message in console
                    console.log("Image not yet fully downloaded.");
                    
                    //show preparing to wait message in console
                    console.log("Preparing to wait for full download.");
                    
                    //get all the files in the folder directory/path
                    var filecheckerfindpathbytimestamp = fs.readdirSync(pathtocheck);
                    console.log("hi1");
    
                    //define variable to store the path of the last donwloaded image foudn by timestamp
                    var lastdownloadedimagefoundbytimestamppath;
                    console.log("hi2");
    
                    //use the timestamp as an index to get the last downloaded file and then check the file at this timestamp(the last downloaded image) and check its file path.
                    //using the timestamp as an image lets us check the file without using the name because the name changes from .tmp to .png for example, so we are unable to get the
                    //the file by its name because of this name , so we use the timestamp to specifc the file we want to check the extention of instead
                    
    
                    //find path of the last downloaded file by using the time to find it
                    filecheckerfindpathbytimestamp.forEach(filecheckerfindpathbytimestampfile => {
    
                      var filecheckerfindpathbytimestamppath = `${pathtocheck}/${filecheckerfindpathbytimestampfile}`;
                      console.log("hi3");
    
                      var filecheckerfindpathbytimestamptimeStamp = fs.statSync(filecheckerfindpathbytimestamppath).mtime.getTime();
                      console.log("hi4");
    
                      if (filecheckerfindpathbytimestamptimeStamp == lastdownloadedimagetimestamp) {
                        console.log("hi5");
    
                        lastdownloadedimagefoundbytimestamppath = filecheckerfindpathbytimestamppath;
                        console.log("hi6");
    
                      }
                    });
                    console.log("hi7");
    
                    
                    //keep checking the file that ends in .tmp untill it changes from .tmp . once the file is no longer endng in .tmp indicating that the file is 
                    //fully downloaded this path that is looking for the fiel path including the .tmp will no longer be valid because of the file path becomeing .png for example
                    // that it has fully downloaded, and the file path will not return true because it is no longer valid with the .tmp extention.
                    //once this path is no longer valid we will know that the file has fully downloaded because that path no longer ends in .tmp. We can then end the while loop.
                    //because file if fully downloaded.
                    //
                    while(fs.existsSync(lastdownloadedimagefoundbytimestamppath) == true){
                    //while((fs.existsSync(lastdownloadedimage)) == true){
                        
                        //Show the file path to the console
                        console.log(lastdownloadedimage);
                    
                        //Wait code
                        //Wait on the image converting page 
                        await page2.type('.jsoninputtextarea', " ", {delay:timetowaitforimagefiledownloaded});
                        
                        //show waiting for file fully download message in console
                        console.log("Waiting for image to fully download.");
                    }
                    
                    
                    //create varaible to find path of the last downloaded file by using the time to find it now that it is fully downloaded
                    var filecheckerfindfullydownloadedfiletimestamp = fs.readdirSync(pathtocheck);
                    
                    //find path of the last downloaded file by using the time to find it now that it is fully downloaded
                    filecheckerfindfullydownloadedfiletimestamp.forEach(filecheckerfindfullydownloadedfilefile => {
    
                      var filecheckerfindfullydownloadedfilepath = `${pathtocheck}/${filecheckerfindfullydownloadedfilefile}`;
                      console.log("hi8");
    
                      var filecheckerfindfullydownloadedfiletimeStamp = fs.statSync(filecheckerfindfullydownloadedfilepath).mtime.getTime();
                      console.log("hi9");
    
                      if (filecheckerfindfullydownloadedfiletimeStamp == lastdownloadedimagetimestamp) {
                        console.log("hi10");
    
                        lastdownloadedimagefoundbytimestamppath = filecheckerfindfullydownloadedfilepath;
                        console.log("hi11");
    
                      }
                    });
                    console.log("hi12");
                    
                    
                    //Set lastdownloaded image to the path the now ends in the file extention (example .png) now instead of .tmp
                    //
                    lastdownloadedimage = lastdownloadedimagefoundbytimestamppath;
                }
                
                
                
                //Remove the path the of the image so we only have image name and file type
                //Before: C:/Users/edtec/Downloads/image.png After: image.png
                lastdownloadedimage = lastdownloadedimage.replace(downloadanduploadpath, "");
                
                
                //Return lastdownloadedimage
                //return lastdownloadedimage;
            //}
                
                //lastdownloadedimage = getlastdownloadedimage(downloadanduploadpath);
                
                //console.log(lastdownloadedimage);
    
                
                console.log(lastdownloadedimage);
```

Comment: So why are you using `...Sync` functions? Use the normal, non-blocking asynchronous functions and put the code that needs to happen "once something has happened" in the callbacks that get triggered when those things happen?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Because the overall program needs to run in order. That is just what I have got so far. Looking for a better solution.

Comment: That's almost certainly not true: if this is a request handler, then the code should only happen "in order" _for that request's code path_, other requests happening simultaneously should not be blocking operations (which `...Sync` operations are). Instead, either use the standard Node callback methodology to ensure that things still happen "in order", but asynchronously so: `fs.readFile(filename, (err, data) => { and then you resume here })`, with that callback obviously being a function of its own, not inlined - or use the modern Promise based API so you can use `async`/`await` properly.

Comment: If this is a request handler, then show the WHOLE request handler from start to finish.  We need to see where the data is coming from.

Comment: @jfriend00 new to node.js, so not sure what that is. This all of what I was able to get so far. I heard there was a way to listen for file changes. That is what I'm looking to do.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I see. Thank You. New to node.js. Heard about a event listener that listens for a file change but was unsure how to implement it. I don't mind it the code provided isn't used as long the end result of detecting a file extension change and then saving the new file name to a variable is achieved

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to figure out when an upload is finished by watching the file system.  You should be hooking into the request handler where the upload is actually taking place and see when it's done from there.

Comment: @jfriend00 Oh Alright. That works. Can you show how to do that?

Comment: You would have to show the code that receives the upload.

Comment: It is a regular file download from the browser.You know,click a download button on a website and then the file goes to your download folder.When you download on chrome the file is first a .tmp file or .crdownload and then it changes to the correct file path once it is fully downloaded. I want to wait until it changes to a file path other than .tmp or .crdownload and then get the file path that it ends up as such as .png. The code in the question is all the code that does this that I have so far. Not holding code back.Can you put an answer that shows how to do the request handler you mentioned?

Comment: @jfriend00 ^^^^

Comment: So, is this code some single user app you're running on your own PC to try to detect when a download into a browser on that same PC is finished and your code is not a server?  If that's the case, I don't think anyone else reading your question thought that's what you were asking about.  I sure didn't.  And your use of `upload` in the title really throws things off too since this is apparently a  download to your hard disk by the browser.

Comment: @jfriend00 Alright. I click the download button and file downloads to the computer. it not anything "fancy" so to speak. I want to get details on the file that downloads. You mentioned the request handlers. Now that we're clear on the question, can you do this and submit an answer?

Comment: A server has request handlers.  As it turns out, you don't have a server (now that I have a clue what you are actually trying to  do).  You will either have to develop a browser plug-in that can see when downloads are complete or you will have to watch the file system and see when you find something interesting.  I don't have any advice on how to do that.

Comment: Probably there's something interesting to use on [`fs.watch()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener).

Comment: @jfriend00 Alright. Yes I was looking at watch as well. Can you make it work with the watch() function?

Comment: @RobomanRobo - Sorry, but I'm not going to write your code for you.  I'd suggest you explore and learn about `fs.watch()` and post back here with your new code if you get stuck and have a more specific question about it and maybe someone else who is more familiar with it can help you then.